# Question of convergence of an infinite number of series with special conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to think about  the following type of problems, and, actually, if we could get some results, they could be applied inside of mathematics, even to some unsolved problems.

I will not now write about potential applications, but proceed to a direct presentation of a problem.

i am studying (although, with no conclusions yet) the sum $$\sum_{3 \leq a_{1,1},a_{1,2}< + \infty} \frac {1}{a_{1,1}a_{1,2}}+\sum_{3 \leq a_{2,1},a_{2,2},a_{2,3}< + \infty} \frac {1}{a_{2,1}a_{2,2}a_{2,3}}+...+ \sum_{3 \leq a_{n,1},a_{n,2},...,a_{n,n+1}< + \infty} \frac {1}{a_{n,1}a_{n,2},...a_{n,n+1}}+...$$.

where $\{a_{1,1}a_{1,2}\}$ and $\{a_{2,1}a_{2,2}a_{2,3}\}$ and ... and $\{a_{n,1}a_{n,2},...a_{n,n+1}\}$ and... are all of density zero in $\mathbb N$ and every term of every sequence is odd.

Does all of this implies convergence of this infinite sum of infinite sums?

Comment: Also asked on MO, and i got downvoted, I really do not know why, so decided to ask here also, because there I got no answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333788/question-of-convergence-of-an-infinite-number-of-series-with-special-conditions

Comment: Which density do you mean?

Comment: @martycohen Suppose that we choose, for example, sequence $ a_{1,1}a_{1,2}$. Then we can order this sequence from the smallest to larger and larger successive elements. When ordered, we can define density in $\mathbb N$ and for the applications that I am interested in the density is zero. The density is called, I think, "natural density", the most simple one, right?